# Removing tags from xml file for BlackBerry

Tags: xml, parsing, blackberry, sax, atom-feed

I am developing a BlackBerry app which needs to read from an xml file. I am able to read it but I would like to remove the tags such as `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`, `<feed>`, `<author>` and so on...

I'm using a BlackBerry 9800 Simulator.

Have checked that my file is an Atom 1.0 file. So how should I remove these tags?

Currently my codes are as of this from what I got from the internet. But it only displays the 'id' and 'updated' date of the file. How can I display/filter certain data away and remove tags?

Thanks,
Hend

```
 class MyApp extends UiApplication{
//creating a member variable for the MainScreen
MainScreen _screen= new MainScreen();
//string variables to store the values of the XML document
String _node,_element;
Connection _connectionthread;

public static void main(String arg[]){
    MyApp application = new MyApp();
    //create a new instance of the application
    //and start the application on the event thread
    application.enterEventDispatcher();
}

public MyApp() {
    _screen.setTitle("XML Parsing");//setting title
    _screen.add(new RichTextField("Requesting....."));
    _screen.add(new SeparatorField());
    pushScreen(_screen); // creating a screen
    //creating a connection thread to run in the background
    _connectionthread = new Connection();
    _connectionthread.start();//starting the thread operation
}

public void updateField(String node, String element) 
{    
    synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) 
    {
        String title = "My App";
        _screen.add(new RichTextField(node + " : " + element));
        if (node.equals(title))
        {
            _screen.add(new SeparatorField());
            }
        }
    } 


private class Connection extends Thread{
    public Connection(){
        super();
    }

    public void run(){
        // define variables later used for parsing

        Document doc;
        StreamConnection conn;

        try{
            //providing the location of the XML file,
            //your address might be different
            conn=(StreamConnection)Connector.open
              ("http://www.google.com");
            //next few lines creates variables to open a
            //stream, parse it, collect XML data and
            //extract the data which is required.
            //In this case they are elements,
            //node and the values of an element
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory
              = DocumentBuilderFactory. newInstance(); 
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder
              = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            docBuilder.isValidating();
            doc = docBuilder.parse(conn.openInputStream());
            doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
            NodeList list=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
            _node=new String();
            _element = new String();
            //this "for" loop is used to parse through the
            //XML document and extract all elements and their
            //value, so they can be displayed on the device

            for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){
                Node value=list.item(i).
                  getChildNodes().item(0);
                _node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
                _element=value.getNodeValue();
                updateField(_node,_element);
            }//end for
        }//end try
        //will catch any exception thrown by the XML parser
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());

        }
      }//end connection function
  }// end connection class
}//end XML_Parsing_Sample
```

Comment: Remove tags? Do you mean you want to ignore the contents of certain tags and grab the contents of others?

Comment: Hi Ray, yes exactly. I want to remove those xml tags, then retrieve certain data from it. E.g. <updated>2011-07-18T02:35:41.000Z</updated><name>Hend</name> <email>hendyWve@gmail.com</email>, I wanna retrieve the date and name. Thanks

Comment: Ok, you could change your getElementsByTagName request to the outer tag instead of a wildcard, then selectively read the inner tags into a custom object and stuff them into a vector. There are a lot of similar questions with very good answers already kicking about on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another method which does the same run() but searching for another tagName. This allows info for several tags to be read and displayed.